# using nth-child in tables tr td

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my code, I want `<td>`s with "$" with a background of `#CCC` in all the `<tr>`s.

Can any one help me how to do this using `nth-child`, pseudo classes?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gqr3J/

Comment: table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ccc;
} this code is nt working for me

Comment: But it select all of the td's not only the 2...? How can i select only the second child?

Comment: The code in the fiddle works like a charm (only selecting the specified children).  @alonblack, I'd recommend double-checking your code against that in the fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

As per the latest css spec, it is not possible to do that, there is no such thing as **find by content** selector (with exception the `:empty` selector where it can be used to find DOM that has empty content).

Another way to achieve that is by using the **find by attribute** selector, but you need to apply small update to your code, adding certain identifiers on all of the `<td>` that have `$` as content.

Example:

html

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td data-rel="$">$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

css

```
table tr td[data-rel='$'] {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
table tr td[data-content='$'] {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td data-content="$">$</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td data-content="$">$</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td data-content="$">$</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
table tr td:nth-child(n){
   background: #ffffff;
   padding: 2px;
}
```

Where n may be any child, i.e: n=1,2,3,4....